# Создание оповещений в систему в определенное время

Tags: python, pyqt, qdatetime, qlcdnumber, qsplashscreen

Нужно сделать так, чтобы в определенное время (*`скажем 14:00`*) выводилось
системное оповещение.

Пытался как-то вытаскивать через `datetime` и выводить оповещение, но без толку.

Также, надо как-то выводить к оповещению картинку. Помогите  пожалуйста.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import pynotify
import subprocess
import os
import json
import tempfile
import datetime


# класс и функция нужны для отображения значка программы в трее.
class SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, parent)
        menu = QtGui.QMenu(parent)
        exitAction = menu.addAction("Off dailyschedule")
        self.setContextMenu(menu)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    trayIcon = SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon("images/settings.png"), w)
    trayIcon.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


mstr='Hello'
os.system('notify-send ' + mstr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QSplashScreen` будет полезен для отображения определенного изображения / текста во время загрузки программы или наприме как вы хотите. 
Вы можете закрыть его, щелкнув по нему или дополнительно вы можете установить таймер для автоматического закрытия через некоторое время. 
Вот простой пример :

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class TestTimer(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.updtTime)

        self.testTimeDisplay = QLCDNumber(self)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setSegmentStyle(QLCDNumber.Filled)
        self.testTimeDisplay.setDigitCount(8)

        self.label = QLabel("Укажите время для оповещения в формате:  ЧЧ:MM:CC")

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(placeholderText="Укажите время для оповещения в формате:  ЧЧ:MM:CC")
        self.lineEdit.setInputMask('99:99:99')

        # чтобы продемонстрировать работу пока вы думаете:
        currentTime = QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('hh:mm:ss')[:6] + '59'
        self.lineEdit.setText(currentTime)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.testTimeDisplay)
        vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        vbox.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        self.updtTime()
        timer.start(1000)

    def updtTime(self):
        currentTime = QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.testTimeDisplay.display(currentTime)

        if currentTime == self.lineEdit.text():
            self.flashSplash()


    def flashSplash(self):
        # Обязательно сохраните ссылку на SplashScreen иначе это будет мусор
        self.splash = QSplashScreen(QPixmap('D:/_Qt/img/pyqt.jpg').scaled(350, 350, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

        # По умолчанию SplashScreen будет находиться в центре экрана.
        # Вы можете переместить его в определенное место, если хотите:
        # self.splash.move(10,10)

        self.splash.show()

        # Закройте SplashScreen через 5 секунды (5000 мс)
        QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.splash.close)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app  = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TestTimer()
    w.show()
    w.setWindowTitle('Cоздание оповещений в определенное время')
    w.resize(430, 170)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]