# Как написать таймер запуска кода Python

Tags: python, время, таймер

Нужно, чтобы код запускался ежедневно в одно и тоже время.

Если делать через `sleep(86400)` после того как код отработал, то время запуска будет постоянно смещаться. Кто знает, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Вроде, модуль [`schedule`](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) умеет такое. Почитайте.

Comment: А сделать поправку на время смещения?  Или смещение в разные дни разное?

Comment: Если использовать `PyQt5`, то ваша задача может выглядеть примерно так: 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/940734

Comment: @V.March  не понял насчет смещения, код должен запускаться каждый день в одно и тоже время. Время выполнения кода каждый день разное.

Comment: Тогда так и напишите: "после того, как код отработал,  время следующего запуска нужно будет смещать на определенные промежутки времени. Значения промежутков времени на которые нужно сместить следующий запуск берутся оттуда-то".

Comment: Судя по всему (так как в задаче не описано) то у вас слип стартует по окончанию выполнения кода?

Comment: В таком случае сохраняйте время старта выполнения кода. В момент когда нужно запускать слип узнаете текущее время и в слип уже запихиваете (86400 - "время  затраченое на выполнение кода").  Время выполнения кода это соответствующе ("текущее время" - "время старта программы").

Comment: Но все же, рекомендация от S. Nick  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/940788/243186 более приемлема. Если нужно запускать в одно и то же ВРЕМЯ, а не через  одинаковые промежутки времени.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.